# As a brand new faculty member who has had no current or pending grants, what to include in "NSF Current and Pending Support"?

Tags: funding, nsf

As a brand new faculty member who has had no current or pending grants, what to include in "NSF Current and Pending Support"?

Basically, should I leave it blank?

Below is the info from the NSF:

> Current and Pending Support Summary PROJECT/PROPOSAL INFORMATION
> Current and Pending Support includes all resources made available to
> an individual in support of and/or related to all of his/her research
> efforts, regardless of whether or not they have monetary value. [1]
> Information must be provided about all current and pending support,
> including this project, for ongoing projects, and for any proposals
> currently under consideration from whatever source [2], irrespective
> of whether such support is provided through the proposing organization
> or is provided directly to the individual. Concurrent submission of a
> proposal to other organizations will not prejudice its review by NSF,
> if disclosed.[3]
>
> [1]If the time commitment or dollar value is not readily
> ascertainable, reasonable estimates should be provided.
>
> [2]For example, Federal, State, local, foreign, public or private
> foundations, non-profits, industrial or other commercial organizations
> or internal funds allocated toward specific projects.
>
> [3]The Biological Sciences Directorate exception to this policy is
> delineated in PAPPG Chapter II.D.2.
>
> IN-KIND CONTRIBUTION INFORMATION Current and Pending Support also
> includes in-kind contributions (such as office/laboratory space,
> equipment, supplies, employees, students). If the in-kind
> contributions are intended for use on the project being proposed to
> NSF, the information must be included as part of the Facilities,
> Equipment and Other Resources section of the proposal and need not be
> replicated in the individual's Current and Pending Support submission.
> In-kind contributions not intended for use on the project/proposal
> being proposed that have associated time obligations must be reported
> below. If the time commitment or dollar value is not readily
> ascertainable, reasonable estimates should be provided.

Comment: Your department or university has someone helping you with the logistics of preparing the grant application… right? You should get their help if you haven’t already, there is absolutely no need for you to grapple with questions that have already been asked a million times by any researcher at your university applying for an NSF grant.

Comment: The key line in the instructions is "Information must be provided about all current and pending support, including this project". So you should list the grant you're applying for, as "pending".

Comment: As for your question, I seem to remember that the rule for what to include is funnily self-referential: “pending support” includes the same NSF grant you are applying to. (Perhaps this is designed to ensure one never has to suffer the embarrassment of leaving the space blank…) But don’t rely on my memory, please seek help from the appropriate staff member at your institution as I was saying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have nothing to report, so there is nothing to report.

NSF wants that the current proposal is listed in this report, however -- because, at the time someone is going to look at your proposal, it is "pending" after all. So you should list that (and mark it as "(this proposal)" after the title you have chose for your proposal). If you use the online form generator that NSF prefers these days (the one at [ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/myncbi](http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/myncbi)), then just add only the current proposal and let it generate its PDF file.

Comment: I'm glad that we have admin staff that know this inside and out, because I always forget that the proposal being submitted counts as a pending proposal for NSF C&P rules. Of course, they also prepare our C&Ps.