# Applying for NSF PRFB. What constitutes "Current and Pending Support" for a postdoc?

Tags: postdocs, funding, nsf

I am applying for the NSF PRFB. I recently began a postdoc position in lab and have been funded since June 2021 by my PI's NIH award. I have no sources of current or pending funding that have been directly awarded to me. I was wondering if anybody knows if, and how, this situation should be noted on the standard NSF format "Current and Pending Support" form?

Because applicants to this fellowship apply as PIs themselves, I am assuming that the form should not list my lab PI's NIH award. If this is the case, then is there any way that I am supposed to indicate that I have indeed been hired and getting paid by someone else for the past 6 mo?

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: It is perfectly okay to ask these questions to the Program Officer for the grant program.  It is part of their job to answer such questions.  Although it is possible to ask sufficiently clueless questions in sufficient quantity as to prejudice your grant applications, these are not such questions.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/173320/40589

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to submit this proposal in about 12 hours, and am not counting on the PO responding in time. Left these peripheral documents to do last minute, and I am now stuck taking shots in the dark online for these types of questions hahaha. So it goes!

Answer (score 1):

You've got nothing to list in terms of funding where you are the (co-)principal investigator, so don't list anything. That doesn't absolve you from submitting the form -- the form will simply not list anything.

Go to SciEnv and generate the pdf file that NSF wants. In your case, there will be no need to enter any information.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying!